# Link Framework go in Project Navigator Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

i have added a Framework in my project on Xcode 6, but when i add it the frameworks goes in the Project Navigator Hierarchy like in in the image above:

[image]

But i remember that on Xcode 5, the linked framework goes in the Framework folder that now doesn't exist anymore, can i move the framework in another folder?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you _try_ it and find out????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked frameworks panel, you can add framework  at other folders. So i think you can move the framework. Or when you click the framework in your left navigate panel,  the left up corner will show the package to which target. It also works.